# Pass array of ids as a single hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hidden-field

I have a message that has recipients, wired this way:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :message_recipients
  has_many :recipients, through: :message_recipients, source: :user
end
```

I pass the user_ids as `GET` param to the new message form to pre-propulate recipients:

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  @message.recipients = User.where(id: params[:user_ids])
end
```

Have set up strong_params like so:

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(
    :subject,
    :body,
    recipient_ids: []
  )
end
```

And have set up the form like so:

```
= simple_form_for @message do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :recipient_ids
```

I expected all this to just work, but then I realized that this hidden field alone is not treated as scalar so it's ignored by strong_params (otherwise I would have to do `:recipient_ids` instead of `recipient_ids: []` but then it would not end up as an array anyway).

So then I thought about doing this:

```
  = hidden_field_tag 'message[recipient_ids][]', @message.recipients.pluck(:id)
```

But then the controller would parse the params like this:

```
message_params[:recipient_ids] => ["1, 2, 3"]
```

instead of:

```
message_params[:recipient_ids] => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

So I had to fallback to the ugly:

```
- @message.recipient_ids.each do |recipient_id|
  = hidden_field_tag 'message[recipient_ids][]', recipient_id
```

And then it all worked.

But I feel this is far from ideal because I now have dozens of DOM elements lying around instead of potentially just one.

**Do you know of any better way to achieve the same result ?**

**Maybe Rails should be a little bit clever when receiving a single scalar field of numbers split by commas ?**

Well, what do you guys think ?

*Rails version: 5.0.0*

Comment: I think you've uncovered both ways to approach this problem in your question: 1) using multiple inputs with [] in the name so that they are processed as an array or 2) serializing the data in one form input, and then unserializing it on the server. Submitting fewer elements may favor the first approach, while more elements may favor the latter approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "select" tag with "multiple" attribute which is properly parsed by the Rails engine as an array of values.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
f.select :recipient_ids, f.object.recipient_ids, {}, multiple: true, style: "display: none;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `recipient_ids` as a simple attribute in `message_params`

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(
    :subject,
    :body,
    :recipient_ids
  )
end
```

And then do `message_params[:recipient_ids].split(","`)

So it will be

```
"1, 2, 3".split(",")
 => ["1", " 2", " 3"]
```

Comment: Where would you place this bit of code ?
Then I would have to think of calling this both in `create` and `update` actions.
You see my point, it starts to clutter the controller of unnecessary logic, don't you think ?

Comment: I would do this in your model.rb. create a new setter that accepts a comma separated value and converts it to an array and in your form, just convert the value to comma separated

Answer (score 0):

yourmodel.rb

```
message_params=(val)
  if val.class==String #if we pass a string
    super(val.split(',')) #split back into array and assign value
  else
    super(val)
  end
end
```

and then in your form builder (assuming simpleform)

```
f.input :message_params, 
  as: :hidden, 
  input_html { 
    value: @yourmodel.message_params.join(',') #split array back into comma separated string
  }
```

and